# Error while executing typescript file with ts-node (after installing the project as global module)

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg, ts-node

Using windows 8.1 64bit & yarn

I'm trying to create a global module which has typescript files in it & running it on the fly using `ts-node` (and not convert files to js)

The sample project is at [github](https://github.com/gmastergreatee/test-ts-global)

I want to run it whenever I execute "gmt" on command line, so I added "bin" in "package.json" and provided appropriate values

And also added shebang "#!/usr/bin/env ts-node" to the main file

But when I execute "gmt" after installing package globally by "yarn global add [directory-path]", I get error:-

```
C:\Users\gmaster>gmt
C:\Users\gmaster\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\gmt\bin\index.ts:6
let term: string = 'guys';
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\gmaster\AppData\L
ocal\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:485:14)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gmaster\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_
modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:158:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Been searching the net for hours.

My aim is to later pass ts filepath to "gmt" so that "gmt" will dynamically import my typescript file and execute something from it using a shared interface-file. But I can't even seem to make the global ts system work, :(

Please help.
Also mention if there's a better way to achieve my aim.

Thankyou very much

```
node version 12.6.0
npm version 6.9.0
yarn version 1.16.0
ts-node version 8.4.1
tsc version 3.6.3
```

All installed globally

Comment: Seems [deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno) is the thing for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: The issue described below has been fixed in [`ts-node@8.9.0`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/releases/tag/v8.9.0) thanks to my report. `--script-mode` now resolves symlinks before looking for the `tsconfig.json` file. The correct shebang to use is `#!/usr/bin/env ts-node-script`, which is now also [documented](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#shebang). Make sure you have the newest version installed globally with `npm -g install ts-node`. (I'm not sure whether you also/still need TypeScript installed globally for this. If yes: `npm -g install typescript`.)

**Outdated**: I'm not sure whether this solves your problem, but I documented my current approach in detail in [this issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/995). In short, many modules (including those of Node.js itself) require that you use the [`--esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) option for the TypeScript compiler. (You can specify this in your `tsconfig.json` file.) In order to be able to use your command from anywhere and not just from within your package directory, you have to use the undocumented [`--script-mode`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/blob/92cf9613828c2ba2fe37b7a0aa7895e122c16185/src/bin.ts#L240-L258) option for [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) or the undocumented [`ts-node-script`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/blob/92cf9613828c2ba2fe37b7a0aa7895e122c16185/package.json#L10) command, which does [the same](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/blob/master/src/bin-script.ts).

In other words, your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) should either be `#!/usr/bin/env -S ts-node --script-mode` or `#!/usr/bin/env ts-node-script`. (The former uses [`-S`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#g_t_002dS_002f_002d_002dsplit_002dstring-usage-in-scripts) to pass arguments to the specified interpreter. If this doesn't work on your platform, you can try to [hack around](http://sambal.org/2014/02/passing-options-node-shebang-line/) this limitation.)

If you want to use the [`bin` functionality](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) of `npm` (e.g. by running [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) from the package directory), the above doesn't work because `--script-mode` does not (yet?) follow symbolic links. To work around this, you can use `#!/usr/bin/env -S ts-node --project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/<your-project>/tsconfig.json` on the first line of your script. This is not ideal, though, as it breaks platform independence. The only other option I see at the moment is to use a bash script instead and call your script from there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it out later today.