# How to get systemd to work with ts-node on raspberry pi?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, systemd, ts-node

I have a raspberry pi that I'm trying to use as a pseudo-host for a nodejs app written in typescript.
Reading a bit into it, I've created and enabled systemd service in order to keep to process running even when I'm not ssh-ed into the pi.

The systemd service looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=test ts app
Documentation=https://example.com
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=NODE_PORT=3000
Type=simple
User=pi
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Documents/NodeApp/
ExecStart=/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js src/server.ts

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've set the global path of ts-node as it didn't find it otherwise. With this ExecStart it's erroring out because it doesn't see the argument following the ts-node path.

```
Apr 26 22:54:35 raspi npm[2814]: /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:14
Apr 26 22:54:35 raspi npm[2814]: function main(argv = process.argv.slice(2), entrypointArgs = {}) {
Apr 26 22:54:35 raspi npm[2814]:                    ^
Apr 26 22:54:35 raspi npm[2814]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Node version: v14.16.1
Npm version: 6.14.12.
Not really sure how to approach the issue next, any hits would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a ts-node systemd service to work by adding this shebang to the beginning of my .ts application: #!/usr/bin/env ts-node-script

(remember to chmod +x your .ts file)

I got it from this answer:

[Error while executing typescript file with ts-node (after installing the project as global module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58346595/error-while-executing-typescript-file-with-ts-node-after-installing-the-project)

I used your question as a resource as well, so thank you for asking it.

My other suggestion (and current fallback) is that you could compile the ts file to javascript and just use node.  If your ts program is going to be running constantly, there are [warning: hearsay] memory leak issues that could occur.